# What's the meaning of "how little he looked forward to his birthdays"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Yet another unusual thing about Harry was **how little he looked forward to his birthdays**. He had never received a birthday card in his life.  ...

What does "*how little he looked forward to his birthdays*" mean? I don't understand what the word '**little**' modifies.

-- From Harry Potter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Little" here applies to the amount Harry looked forward to birthdays. Most children can't wait for their birthday to come, along with the associated cards, presents and cake; Harry never got any of those, so he didn't look forward to his birthday.

Answer (score 1):

Basically here the sentence:

> **How little he looked forward to his birthdays.**

implies that harry never really was interested or wanted to get to his birthday, the part "how little he looked forward" means that he doesn't really care if they happen or not.